# Prove by induction that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k} k^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: induction, sums-of-squares

Prove by mathematical induction that

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:~~~~ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k} k^{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

**Step 1**: Show true for $n = 1$:

LHS: $(-1)^{(1+0)} \cdot 0^{2} + (-1)^{(1+1)} \cdot 1^{2} = 1$

RHS: $\frac{0(0+1)}{2} + \frac{1(1+1)}{2} = 1$

**Step 2**: Show "if true for $n = p$, then true for $n = p + 1$":

So we start by the LHS of  $n = p + 1$ and try to get to the RHS of it, by using the equality for $n = p$.

The first step involves breaking out the highest term in the sum.

$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2} = (-1)^{(2p+2)} (p+1)^{2} + \sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^{(p+k)} k^{2} $

Replacing the last term with the equality for $n = p$.

$(-1)^{2p+2} (p+1)^{2} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{p+k} k^{2} = (-1)^{2p+2} (p+1)^{2} + \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$

Since 2p+2 is an even number, the -1 becomes a 1:

$(-1)^{2p+2} (p+1)^{2} + \frac{p(p+1)}{2} = (p+1)^{2} + \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$

All that is required now is to show that this equals to $\frac{(p+1)(p+2)}{2}$, but there seems to be a $(p+1)$ too many in the first term for it to work.

**Question 1:** Where have I gone wrong in the above attempt?

**Question 2:** Is it more productive to attempt to prove

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:~~~~ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k} k^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k$

instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this step you have made an error:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2} = (-1)^{(2p+2)} (p+1)^{2} + \sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^{(p+k)} k^{2}$$
This should be 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2} = (-1)^{(2p+2)} (p+1)^{2} + \sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2}.$$Notice the extra $+1$ in the exponent of $(-1)$ in the last sum. We can remove it by factoring out a $-1$ to get
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2} =  (p+1)^{2} - \sum_{k=0}^{p}(-1)^{(p+k)} k^{2}.$$
By the assumption this is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p+1}(-1)^{(p+1+k)} k^{2} =  (p+1)^{2} -\frac{p(p+1)}{2}.$$
Now we can easily work it out:
$$(p+1)^2 - \frac{p(p+1)}{2} = (p+1)(-\frac{p}{2} + p +1)= (p+1)\frac{p+2}{2}$$
as desired.